# Uploading PUT request is sent twice by Angular ServiceWorker

Tags: angular, file-upload, service-worker, put, angular-service-worker

We are using a serviceWorker in Angular 7 application. 
When the user uploads a file (an image or PDF) from the app via a `PUT` request to AWS S3, there are 2 `PUT` requests triggered instead of 1. The first `PUT` request is from the ServiceWorker, though it shouldn't, the upload is done from the main thread.  The second one is not from the ServiceWorker and seems it is sent with no file.

As a result, the file is uploaded incorrectly as 0 bytes in size to S3. The issue happens only when we run the app with ServiceWorker enabled.
It seems like ServiceWorker is caching the upload requests.

How do I avoid this?

This is what I am seeing in the network tab in dev tools: https://prnt.sc/odoaac

Here is **angular.json** configuration:

```
"production": {
    "fileReplacements": [
      {
        "replace":"apps/echo/src/environments/environment.ts",
        "with":"apps/echo/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    ],
  "serviceWorker": true,
  "ngswConfigPath": "apps/echo/src/ngsw-config.json",
  "optimization": true,
  "outputHashing": "all",
  "sourceMap": false,
  "extractCss": true,
  "namedChunks": false,
  "aot": true,
  "extractLicenses": true,
  "vendorChunk": false,
  "buildOptimizer": true,
  "budgets": [
    {
      "type": "initial",
      "maximumWarning": "2mb",
      "maximumError": "5mb"
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is **ngsw-config.json** dataGroups:

```
"dataGroups": [
  {
    "cacheConfig": {
      "maxSize": "1",
      "maxAge": "0u",
      "timeout": "10m",
      "strategy": "freshness"
    },
    "name": "API",
    "urls": [
      "https://api.editorial.reali.com",
      "https://api.editorial.reali.com/",
      "https://api.editorial.reali.com/*",
      "https://api.editorial.reali.com/**",
      "https://s3.amazonaws.com",
      "https://s3.amazonaws.com/",
      "https://s3.amazonaws.com/*",
      "https://s3.amazonaws.com/**",
      "/version.json"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "GoogleFonts",
    "cacheConfig": {
      "maxSize": "20",
      "maxAge": "5d",
      "timeout": "1s",
      "strategy": "performance"
    },
    "urls": [
      "https://fonts.googleapis.com/**"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Question, are you seeing 2 files in S3 after the requests execute? In other words, is the application actually uploading the file twice?

Comment: @AndrewHill there is only 1 file in S3. Two uploading request are sent to exactly the same url (the same bucket, filename etc), I guess it may upload twice and override the same file

Answer (score 1):

There is actually only one PUT request to the server. You should be able to confirm this from your S3 access logs.

What happens in the devtools screenshot (I'm re-adding it here for future reference!) is this:

1. page JS sends a PUT request that the SW intercepts
2. SW, after intercepting the request, decides to make an *actual* request to the server
3. When an actual request is made, the browser sees that the destination domain is different
4. Because of the different domain, the browser automatically sends a CORS preflight request (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) to the server and *confirms* that the server supports PUT
5. Server answers to the preflight request and says that PUT is ok
6. Browser sends the real, final, only PUT request to the server

For some reason somewhere in here your file is dropped. I'm not sure why since I haven't dealt with file uploads in Service Workers.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the same issue.  https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/29629

Docs How to bypass the service worker:
https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-devops#bypassing-the-service-worker